# DesignInstance does not work in VS2013

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

Visual Studio does not show design time data with DesignInstance attribute. I have checked `DesignInstance` with/without MVVM Light. I have spend a lot of time to fix the issue (checked similar queestions on StackOverflow too) but `DesignInstance` simply does not work.

**Project:**

- `SearchIdView`.
- `SearchIdViewModel` - real View Model.
- `DesignSearchIdViewModel` - inherits from `SearchIdViewModel` and contains design time data (properties are assigned in constructor).

**Environment:**

- VS2013 SP3
- Net 4.0
- MvvmLight 5.0.2.0

**SearchIdView.xaml**

```xml
<Window x:Class="App1.View.SearchIdView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ignore="http://www.ignore.com"
    xmlns:design="clr-namespace:App1.Design"
    mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
    DataContext="{Binding SearchId, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance d:Type=design:DesignSearchIdViewModel,IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
    >
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Test}" />
</Grid>
```

**SearchIdViewModel.cs**

Property from `SearchIdViewModel`

```c#
public const string TestPropertyName = "Test";
private string _test;
public string Test
{
  get
  {
    return _test;
  }
  set
  {
    Set(TestPropertyName, ref _test, value);
  }
}
```

Do you have any idea why `DesignInstance` does not work in this case?

### Workaround

- remove `d:DataContext` from view
- add interface `ISearchIdViewModel` (it is empty)
- `SearchIdViewModel` inherits from `ISearchIdViewModel`
- change `ViewModelLocator` (below)

**ViewModelLocator.cs**

```c#
public class ViewModelLocator
{
  static ViewModelLocator()
  {
    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
    if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
    {
      SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ISearchIdViewModel,Design.DesignSearchIdViewModel>();
    }
    else
    {
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ISearchIdViewModel, SearchIdViewModel>();
    }
  }

  public SearchIdViewModel SearchId
  {
    get { return (SearchIdViewModel) ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISearchIdViewModel>(); }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `d:DesignInstance` declaration is malformed.  You specify the property name `d:Type` instead of `Type`, so the property is not assigned correctly.  Either replace `d:Type` with `Type`, or leave the property name off entirely and let it be inferred as the default property.

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance d:Type=design:DesignSearchIdViewModel,
                                 IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
```

Should become:

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=design:DesignSearchIdViewModel,
                                 IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
```

Or, alternatively:

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance design:DesignSearchIdViewModel,
                                 IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
```

<sub>(line wrapping added for readability)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Another cause that might make d:DesignInstance not to work is that **all data must be properties** not just public variables of mock class! I know that it was not your problem, but it should be checked if for someone it does not work.

Will **not work** with:

```
public class MockFile
{
    public FilePRJO FilePRJO = new FilePRJO();
}
```

But it **will work** with:

```
public class MockFile
{
    public FilePRJO _filePRJO = new FilePRJO();

    public FilePRJO FilePRJO
    {
        get
        {
            return _filePRJO;
        }
    }
}
```